# Load JSON data into a JS class

Tags: javascript, json, class, asynchronous

I'm using a modular approach for a JavaScript application: `Floor` is a subtype of `Tile`, and it has a lot of subtypes itself, but those are declared in JSON files, instead of other JavaScript classes.
The thing is: To load a JSON file on the client side, I need to either do a synchronous request, which hurts performance, or an async one, which (apparently) doesn't let me put the data on the instance.

```
class Floor extends Tile {
    constructor(name) {
        $.getJSON('./data/tiles/floors/' + name + '.json', (json) => {
            let data = json;

            super(data.token, data.fg_color, data.bg_color, false);

            this.name = data.name;
            this.hardness = data.hardness;
            this.hitpoints = data.hitpoints;
            this.max_speed = data.max_speed;
            this.see_through = data.see_through;
            this.visible = data.visible;
            this.indestructible = this.hardness == -1 ? true : false;
        });
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make this model work, or am I better using JavaScript classes for everything? I like this JSON approach a lot.

Comment: What you can do is to create a `Floor` factory that returns a promise containing a `Floor` instance initialized with the values from the JSON.

Comment: Could you explain that in more detail?

Comment: Instances constructions should be synchronous operations, so just separate the async stuff from the constructor. Here's the way I would do: https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/ycrnm199/

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. All the `Promise` stay pending and the `console.log` never triggers.

Comment: It's working [fine for me](https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/ug2rzeac/). My best guess is that your `.getJSON` is getting an error and not calling the resolve function.

Comment: Yes, there was an error with the JSON. It works, but it seems that instantiating a lot of these is quite slow. So I feel that's not the proper way to do this.

Comment: By slow what you mean by that? If you are creating a lot of Tiles with the same JSON `name`, then you should probably look into caching the JSON contents. Using Promises is a quite common pattern (`$.getJSON` is actually also returning promises in case you didn't notice.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141801/discussion-between-william-fernandes-and-derek-).

Answer (score 0):

> or an async one, which (apparently) doesn't let me put the data on the
>   instance

I think it is because `this` inside `$.getJSON()` does not refer to the class, but the jQuery function. (Try doing `console.log(this)` within the function and see what it outputs.)

So, you need to preserve the context of `this`. Here's one way:

```
class Floor extends Tile {
    constructor(name) {
        let self = this;
        $.getJSON('./data/tiles/floors/' + name + '.json', (data) => {
            super(data.token, data.fg_color, data.bg_color, false);
            self.name = data.name;
            self.hardness = data.hardness;
            self.hitpoints = data.hitpoints;
            self.max_speed = data.max_speed;
            self.see_through = data.see_through;
            self.visible = data.visible;
            self.indestructible = self.hardness == -1 ? true : false;
        });
    }
}
```

You could also use [jQuery.proxy()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) if you are adamant about using the keyword `this`.